# Cloning Azure DevOps Workitems across Projects

Tags: azure-devops

We have created a Project in Azure Devops using Work Items Such as User Stories and Tasks to link activities together. The purpose of this Project is to be used as a template, and any new project we create we want a method of transporting all of the work items from the template project into this new project.

Please could anyone advise or direct me in the direction of how this can be achieved, any API document which could be used? We like the idea of a pythons script for example to complete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cloning Azure DevOps Workitems across Projects

You could query those workitems and select the options **Move to the team project**:

[image]

Besides, you could also select to clone those workitems by export to the CSV file and import to the new project:

[image]

[image]